# MySQL Query Zipcode to Points

Tags: mysql

2 Tables

Table **geo_postal** contains a postal code (**code**), latitude (**lat**), and longitude (**lng**)

Table **geo_loc** contains a Post ID (**post_id**), latitude (**lat**), and longitude (**lng**)

Currently running 2 queries to get the desired results. Is it possible to create a single query?

```
    SELECT lat, lng
    FROM geo_postal
    WHERE code = " . $postal_code . "
    LIMIT 1
```

Then using the *results* of **$lat** and **$lng** in the following query:

```
    SELECT 
        post_id,
        ( 3959 * acos( 
            cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
          * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(" . $lng . ") ) 
          + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) 
          * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) 
        ) AS distance 
        FROM geo_loc  
        HAVING distance < 25 
        ORDER BY distance 
        LIMIT 0, 10
```

Is there a way to do this as a single, effecient query?

Comment: Your query isn't particularly optimal, because the great circle formula is costly to calculate and probably can't use an index.  That being said, does your query work, or what is the actual problem?

Comment: The query does work. The question is if the 2 queries can be made into one.

Also, if a square formula is less costly, I'd be willing to use that.